# Swift and UrlSession, UrlSessionTask and blocking calls

Tags: swift, networking, urlsession

I am implementing queries to my web server within Swift - I am a swift newbie, by the way.

To do a post call, I am using the following :

```
    func DoPost() -> Bool
    {
        var data: Data? = nil;
        var request: URLRequest?;
        var task: URLSessionTask?;
        
        // all variables preceded with 'm_' are member variables and are
        // created and initialised elsewhere in the class

        if(nil != m_Params)
        {
            data = m_Params!.data(using: .utf8);
        }
        
        request = URLRequest(url: m_TargetUrl!);
        request!.httpMethod = "POST";
        
        if(nil != data)
        {
            request!.httpBody = data!;
        }
        
        if(nil != m_Headers)
        {
            m_Session!.configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = m_Headers!;
        }
        
        task = m_Session!.dataTask(with: request!, completionHandler: self.PostCompletion);
        task!.resume();
    }
    
    private func PostCompletion(data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void
    {
        // do something intelligent here
    }
```

What I have not been able to determine is if the call to `task.resume()` is a blocking call.

I am wanting to know this as there are certain situations where I will need to have a "conversation" with the server, as opposed to 'simply' getting some data in a one off call.

This "conversation" would normally take place on a separate worker thread.

Is there a standard way of going about this ?

Comment: `task.resume()` is not a blocking call. It is asynchronous, and will asynchronously call the completion handler supplied to `dataTask` when it is done.

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, I had a few stylistic/design observations: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/7756a8239d6564385ad341fe6221691f

Comment: Thank you @Rob for your comments. Since my question related to having a "conversation" with a server (ie multiple requests/replies, one after the other), how would you advise to best handle that, please ?

Comment: Well, it depends. Is every reply an immediate response from the server to some request from the client? The standard POST pattern is fine. I.e. POST, get reply, and in the processing of the server response, then trigger next POST and repeat. If not, then it might suggest a far more complicated design. You need to be more specific in your description than just “a conversation”. How does your “conversation” differ from a standard HTTP api?

Comment: When I say "conversation", I mean 3 or 4 posts, the first triggered by the user and the others sent immediately after the previous reply from the server, the contents of which depend on the contents from the server.

Comment: I’m still not quite following you, but let me ask it this way: Is it the case that, from the device perspective, that it is always sending a request to the server and getting an immediate response from that server, and it is the repetition of that process that constitutes the “conversation”? Or is it more like a SMS/chat feature that sometimes the device sends messages to the server and sometimes that the server sends messages to the device (i.e., not only as an immediate response to some client request)?

Comment: The former is a simply HTTP pattern. Super simple. `URLSession` is all you need. The latter is a little more complicated, requiring some way(s) (e.g., web sockets, push notifications, etc.) for the server to send a message to a client without it just being the immediate response to some device request. So, is your “conversation” merely a sequence of HTTP requests and responses, or is it independent messages from client-to-server and/or from server-to-client.

Comment: You are right with the first assumption, the device "is always sending a request to the server and getting an immediate response from that server, and it is the repetition of that process that constitutes the conversation".

Comment: Then you just POST, get reply, and in the processing of the server response, then invoke the next POST when you’re done processing the prior response.